# Embed vimeo videos where token is required

Tags: html, video, embed, vimeo

I'd like to know whether there's a way to directly embed a `vimeo` video into a website or whether there's a way to get a stable link to the `MP4` file. 
E.g. this page: http://www.landfunker.de/ktv/detail.php?rubric=93&nr=86411. The video is only launched when accessing it from that page. In the source code, I see links like

> fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3026/7/190133161/631209312.mp4?token=587a20e2_0xece9d9d127813f2b792edb30032d4d9b0a7c484f

However, the tokens expire, right. Any tips? Any workarounds.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Vimeo iframe embed code to embed videos on your site:

- https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/sections/203874347-Embedding-Videos
- https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

To get the MP4 links for video files, you'll need to be a Vimeo PRO or Business member. Video file links are returned in the individual video's response from the API.

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]
```

You can use the API's [JSON fields filter](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#json-filter) to *only* return the video file links:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]?fields=files
```

Finally, note that you can only retrieve the video file links for videos on your own PRO or Business account. Vimeo does not provide a way to retrieve the video file links for videos on other user accounts.

API documentation can be found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely embed a Vimeo video into a website - Vimeo provides instructions on their website:

> To get your video's embed code, go to its video page and click the Share button. Then click the +Show options link that appears above the embed code field to reveal a preview of your embedded video with the Basic customization options. Once you've made your adjustments, you can copy the embed code and paste it wherever you'd like to embed your video.

They also provide an API based embed approach using oEmbed. There is a JavaSCript example using this here:

- https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-oembed-examples/blob/master/oembed/js-example.html

This basically calls the API with the URL of the video to embed and the response includes HTML which you append to your page.

Comment: not sure if I got it across completely. I do not own that video. The video from the page is owned by PRO users and they have some protection in place (I'm not very familiar with vimeo, but once trying the code from github, it just says that due to privacy settings, the video could not be loaded). I just want to embed this video on my page but I then conclude: there is no way to embed such a video.